# Building an rpm file with a unique qualifier appended

Tags: rpm

I'm building RPMs in a continuous integration environment, and I need to distinguish between successive builds, but obviously the spec file does not get modified on each checkin.

The spec file header contains something like

```
Version:        1.0beta7
Release:        1.1
```

I'd like to override it so that the the built RPM will have a qualified appended to the version, e.g.

```
Version:        1.0.beta7.2913
```

Assuming that the qualifier is already available, as an environment variable, what's the easiest way of appending a qualified to the version?

Comment: Please, check my answer for similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58844658/265374

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fairly easy:

```
Version: 1.0.beta7.%(echo $ENVVAR)
```

You can run whatever command you want inside %(); just make sure there's no whitespace in the output.

Personally, I think it's a touch cleaner to stick it in a variable at the top:

```
%define buildnumber %(whatever command to get the build number)

Version: 1.0.beta7.%{buildnumber}
```

Or to make it conditional on the variable being set:

```
Version: 1.0.beta7%{?buildnumber:.%{buildnumber}}
```

That should only print the '.' if %buildnumber is set.

Comment: This looks exactly what I'm looking for, I'll try it out.

Comment: Works great, one final question. I want to append the whole '.$ENVVAR' or nothing at all. How can do it so that I don't end up with a version of `1.0.beta7.` (note the final dot) when ENVVAR is not set?

Comment: Something like %{?buildnumber:.%{buildnumber}}.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this approach is that such specs require an externally-defined parameter (buildnumber)... for example re-building an .src.rpm file will most probably yield a different version number than the one originally used by your CI system.

I think what you really want is embed the source version (e.g., subversion revision number) into the RPM version number. I generate RPM .specs from templates. The template is source-controlled and the build process generates a real spec file from it, so

```
Version: 1.0.beta7.svn@SVN_REV@
```

becomes something like

```
Version: 1.0.beta7.svn1234
```